# Alfresco HotSwapAgent extraclass

Tags: maven, alfresco, hotswapagent

i'm trying to configure HotSwapAgent for hotreloading my Alfresco AIO project.
At the end of this tutorial https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/sdk-hot-reload-hotswap.html, i can reload my java classes, but not files in /META-INF/resources folder.

This appear in the console when i start the Alfresco project:

```
 HOTSWAP AGENT: 18:40:26.656 DEBUG (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginConfiguration) - Unable to set extraClasspath to [file:/C:/.../my-all-in-one/my-all-in-one-platform-jar/target/classes/] on classLoader org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper$TypeHelperClassLoader@12dca552. Only URLClassLoader is supported.

*** extraClasspath configuration property will not be handled on JVM level ***
```

and this is my file hotswap-agent.properties in src/main/resources folder

```
autoHotswap=true 
extraClasspath=${project.build.outputDirectory}
disabledPlugins=Hibernate,Spring
extraWebappContext=${project.basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/resources;
webappDir=${project.basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/resources;
LOGGER.org.hotswap.agent=DEBUG
LOGGER.org.hotswap.agent.plugin=TRACE
LOGGER.org.hotswap.agent.watch=TRACE
LOGGER.org.hotswap.agent.command=TRACE
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What resources are you trying to reload? Static assets (HTML/CSS/JS) for Share? Repo?

Comment: Hi, yes (HTML/CSS/JS) in folder META-INF/resources...it's a repo project with the sdk 3.0...